# Algorithms for evaluating $\pi$

Tags: algorithms, big-list, pi

A year ago I learned about the [Spigot algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spigot_algorithm?wprov=sfla1) and I calculated many digits of $\pi$. That aroused my interest in algorithms. So my question is:

> What are other algorithms for calculating $\pi$?

An article reference will also be appreciated. Whether fast or slow, I love every algorithm.

Comment: I modified the question. Asking for "your favorite X" is a guarantee to get your question closed.

Comment: You can start with [Machin-like formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula) and [Approximations of π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80) on Wikipedia.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Thanks, I am a new user, I didn't know about that.

Comment: Modern calculations include contribution from [*Ramanujan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan), [*Borwein's iterative algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein%27s_algorithm) and [*BBP formulae*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula).  See also [*the quest of $\pi$*](https://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/pi-quest.pdf).

Comment: You might be interested in the book *Pi and the AGM* by Borwein and Borwein.